# Passing a function name to an event class in an event bus system

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple event bus system to get familiar with this model. I have an addEvent function which takes an event name (string) and a function. I'm having trouble establishing my event class.

```
// Event class to define our event
class Event
{
public:
    // function is some function that needs to be executed later
    Event(const string eventName, void * function)
    {
        msgEvent.first = event;
        msgEvent.second = function;
    }

    string getEvent(){
        return msgEvent;
    }
private:
    pair<string, void*> msgEvent;
};
```

so when I make a call addEvent("open", openFunction), I would like to store this information as part of an Event.

I'm having a hard time understanding how I can store the function and if I'm correctly passing a function in the constructor as a parameter.

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you've shown? In what way does it fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: I don't think I'm storing the function correctly or I fail to understand how I'll be able to pass a function to the void * function parameter in the Event constructor.

Comment: Please expand on "I'm having a hard time understanding" as that's not an acceptable problem statement at present. Similarly "I don't think" and "I fail to understand". You have to actually explain, in detail, what problem you face, or why you think you face a problem.

Comment: I don't see any code where you are "passing a function in the constructor as a parameter." What have you tried, and in what way, if any, have you failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function pointers or `std::function`. `void*` is for sure not correct. In any case, you need to know what signature your function has. Let's say, your functions do not take any input and do not return. Then, their signature is `void()`

Then, you can use the following code:

```
#include<functional>
#include<string>
class Event
{
public:
    // function is some function that needs to be executed later
    Event(const std::string eventName, std::function<void()> functionName)
    {
        msgEvent.first = eventName;
        msgEvent.second = functionName;
    }

    std::string getEvent(){
        return msgEvent.first;
    }

    void execute() {
        msgEvent.second();
    }

private:
    std::pair< std::string, std::function<void()> > msgEvent; // why are you using
                                                              // std::pair here?
};
```

Now, you can write

```
Event myEvent( "open", [](){ /* do something */ } );
myEvent.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was having trouble understanding!